# why jdk on centos not work

Tags: java, centos, installation

I install jdk on my centos in my vmware.
I put whole folder in the directory /usr/local/java,and set the environment varable in the file /etc/profile like this:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java
export CLASSPATH=.:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
export PATH=/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

And then I type into "source /etc/profile".After that I execute java -version,it's ok.But when I open another terminal the command java -version didn't work again.why?

Comment: Do you understand what the `source` command does?  Read about it.  It is a shell built-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason could be that your profile needs to be read/exec. Try to logout and log back in. That should do the trick. 
Or use command "source"